# Modern Document Library Accents

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience

On modern document libraries on SharePoint Online the colours/accents change from the default colours of the theme.

For example, the document library icon changes from default blue to green.

Is there a way to prevent this colour change from happening?  So that it stays with the default theme colours i.e. blue.

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now, there is not. I've tried multiple techniques to change colours and customize the modern pages. I have tried updating the color through the masterpage, aspx, [Customizer Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-field-customizer) and [JSON formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting) to no avail. You can't even inject CSS to change the color of the block you're referring to. They have a lonnnng way to go with these modern pages and this is just one of the pains our customer share with you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to Anthony above, I understand that you are trying to create a branding on the modern experience. This is now possible, by using using PowerShell.

You can create your own branding through [Theme Generator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-json-schema) and copy the PowerShell/json scheme provided which can use to set the custom branding. You can follow [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-theming/sharepoint-site-theming-powershell).
[image]

You can hide all the given option by default using: `Get-HideDefaultThemes`.

Comment: No.  Not trying to create anything. I'm trying to prevent what seems to be default behaviour where the accents change to unrelated colours not in keeping with the applied default colours.  E.g. in the default blue coloured theme we suddenly see green and purple appearing in document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Move to Site Settings -- Change the look and select one theme and try it out .

In your case , I supposed you are using default theme which is "Office" , if you want to use blue theme color , you can use [**SharePoint Color Palette Tool**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=38182) to create a new theme .

Please refer to following web link :

http://itgroove.net/align/change-color-spo-modern-experience/

Comment: The accent colours still change to other colours. For organisations that have strict branding guidelines this isn’t acceptable. It’s also annoying that Microsoft make stuff like this so difficult to control & it changes from SharePoint version to version.